# Can I create a Body inside mousePressed function in p5.play?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
 function mousePressed() {
     if (mouseY < 350) {
         // Every time a mouse press create a new box.
         box = new Box(mouseX,mouseY,50,50);
         //strokeweight(3);
         //fill("red");
         box.display();
         console.log("display");
     }
  }
```

This is function is created outside the draw function only

Comment: It seems your code answers your own question, so I assume you're running into some kind of issue. What is the actual problem when using that code?

Comment: My aim was to create a new box every time, i click on screen and then display it. The above code was creating only one box and it moved with the mouse. So i took var Box as array and stored all the boxes and displayed it using for loop.
Problem Fixed.